# how to use cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a method in scrollView:didScroll like this:

```
[self.navigationCollectionView moveWhiteLineToPointX:middleX WithWidth:middleWidth animated:NO];
```

I don't want this method be called multiple times if user is scrolling fast, so I want to use `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object`

```
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument
```

I don't know how to feed the correct parameters for this API, especially for the target and the argument. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:) object:nil];
```

Comment: why cancel scrollViewDidScroll here?

Answer (score 0):

For canceling:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(yourSelectorFunction) object:nil];
```

And for calling perform selector:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourSelectorFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
```