# import non-ARC code compiled .a file in ARC enabled project

Tags: ios, objective-c, svgkit

There is a SVGKit on github is compiled in non-arc code, and I get its library file, named SVGKit.a and some header files.

However, my app project is developed on iOS 7 and above, so by default it is managed by ARC.

My question is, is it safe to link the non-ARC library `.a` file into my project and use it like usual? If not, then how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe

From an ARC point of view, certainly. ARC operates at compiler level - and your library is *already* compiled. One way or another, it is already doing whatever memory management it is doing.

Now, there may be *other* reason why you'd have trouble linking to a library; but that would have nothing to do with ARC.

Comment: could you elaborate `there may be other reason why you'd have trouble linking to a library`? It is a single .a file and some header files, and I follow the github guidance to link and setup it into my project.

Comment: Don't make trouble for yourself. If it works, it works! If it doesn't, then you can ask about that. But I assure you, you won't have any trouble that is caused by some sort of ARC mismatch.

Comment: Now I see. I am trying to make a prototype. BTW, I am a big fan of your book:)

Comment: I am a big fan of big fans! :) Seriously, that last paragraph is just a way of covering the bases - _if_ something goes wrong, I don't want you to think it's because of ARC. It isn't. ARC is not an issue.

Comment: forgive me, I notice you delete your answer on my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100259/how-to-use-cancelpreviousperformrequestswithtarget?answertab=active#tab-top, mind to share more?

Comment: You did not share enough code, in the question, for me to know what you were doing or trying to accomplish. So my answer was not helpful.